# Make std::fstream write to end of file but read from beginning

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fstream

The title explains this fairly well. I have a file that I truncate and write to (as a test to control the initial contents of the file). I then want to do read/write operations with that file. Specifically, I want to write to the end of the file, but read from the beginning.

Procedure:

```cpp
// (1) Make an initial file (truncated std::ofstream) with some contents
// (2) Close initial file stream
// (3) Re-open file with read and write permissions (std::fstream)
// (4) Set stream read pointer to beginning of file
// (5) Set stream write pointer to the end of file
```

This is somewhat implied along with the question, but what `std::fstream::openmode` bitwise parameters should I use to open the file (or is the default `std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out` good enough)?

Answer (score 0):

fstream doesn't have separate read and write positions you need to seek when changing from read to write.

`seekg` and `seekp` both call `pubseekpos` which for `fstream` does the same for both input and output: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/seekpos.

Depending on your use case a separate read and write stream on the same file might work.

Comment: Thank you! If I wrap a class around this, I imagine I could use some members to keep track of the separate read and write positions. Would you be willing to implement this using member functions `read()` (which would set the position of the stream to the where it last read from), and `write()` (which writes to the end)?

Comment: Yes this could be the correct approach. Note however that the read buffer is discarded on seek so if you do a small read, then a small write and then another small read it will not be very efficient, in this case 2 separate streams would be better

Comment: If the file is being modified by two separate streams, would I need to update the read stream every time the file is written to, or would the read stream update automatically?

Comment: it depends what you are doing, if you only append to the end of the stream then it will just work (you might need to clear the `eof` flag if the reader reaches the current end of the file), if not then the read stream will potentially have stale data in its read buffer

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it. Could you outline this method in your answer? It would be helpful to see some code.